# Store offline data with React Native and Firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native

Is it possible to save data offline with React Native and Firebase? As far as I know it is possible to do so in iOS/Android SDKs of Firebase, but I'm not sure about Web SDK. I want to save login information so that user will not have to re-login again and also save some other user data for example user's posts.

I've read that some time ago offline data save was not possible, but maybe the situation has changed.

Should I in general use Firebase Web SDK with React Native or it is better to use something like https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase instead?

Comment: By _offline data_ if you mean [offline capability](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities) I believe Web SDK with react-native does not support that. You may need to use react-native-firebase or any other package that supports native Firebase SDK

Comment: Does react-native-firebase has the same API as official Firebase? As far as I understood from the documentation, it resembles the original API. So an existing RN + Firebase app should work (at least in majority of cases). Is that correct?

Comment: react-native-firebase package tries to use the same API from the Wep API of Firebase so most of the code and syntax you used for Web API can work with it. There are more information on their documentation

Answer (score 0):

To store data on the user's device you should use [react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob).

Answer (score 0):

There is offline data persistence feature for the web SDK,check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) out